# How can I test an Office 365 / Exchange 365 email account without logging into it?

Tags: microsoft-office-365

We've had a recent change in company policy that as the administrator, I'm not allowed to login to people's accounts even to test them out initially; this only causes problems when I need to test if an additional email account that the user has, has been added to the user.

I'm not the main administrator of Office 365 / Exchange 365, but I do have permissions to look at some of the settings there (not sure which ones).

Is there a way to tell if a user has a seperate mailbox added to their account without logging in to their account in Outlook or on the Office 365 / Exchange 365 OWA?

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options here.

If I were going about this with an active user, I would add their alias and send a message to the alias asking for a response (or requesting a read receipt).  If you are checking mailbox access - grant them access and do the same thing.

Further: 
You can validate mail flow thru Message Traces.

If your subscription supports it - you can use eDiscovery to search for test messages. Be wary here, you get direct access to messages from eDiscovery searches which may be a violation of your company policy.

If you want to validate SendAs, or secondary mailboxes access from a client - there is no work around.  You will need to get the user to verify for you. This is actually pretty common method for dealing with user issues (you can even leverage a remote desktop sharing tool like Lync to view the user session).